# How can I keep corresponding code in one place for several versions of the same app?

Tags: java, android, module

I am developing several song book apps with basically the same functionality. I have developed "Evening Light Songs" and "Wahrheits Lieder". The main things that change between the two apps are the images and the database.

Right now I have them in separate projects. When I find a bug or make an update, I have to go to each project and change my code. Is there a way to bundle the code that is the same in both apps into one place so I only have to change it once? Then I could have other classes specific to each app that I would change separately.

Thanks!

Comment: Have one project with two app modules and one library module. The library module would contain the common code. Each app module would represent one of your apps, and it would depend upon the library module to bring in that common code.

Comment: For an accurate answer, we would have to see entire codebase to see what exactly is the same and what not.
Besides the comment by @CommonsWare, you might also take a look at flavors to switch your database and other resources.